# Set Continue Button to resume previous Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a 'Continue' and a 'New Game' button on the mainscreen. When 'New Game' button is clicked the following code is run:

```
Case:R.id.new_button:     
Intent  = new Intent(this, Difficulty.class);
        startActivity(openDifficulty);
        break;
```

Which then opens the 'Difficulty' activity screen, which contains the 'Easy' and 'Hard' buttons.
When 'Easy' or 'Hard' button is clicked for example this runs:

```
case R.id.easy_button:
        Intent openEasy = new Intent(this, EasyGameScreen.class);
        startActivity(openEasy);
        break; 

case R.id.hard_button:
        Intent openHard = new Intent(this, HardGameScreen.class);
        startActivity(openHard);
        break;
```

Which then takes the user to corresponding level

How can I get the 'Continue' button to resume the previous game from the exact same point it was left?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

you need to save the state of the game as per your game requirement, then check whether any save state is there or not in your first activity, if is there then show the continue button, and onclick on that button load the game as per the save state, and you are done

Comment: so how do I save the state of the game. Is it something like super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: use sharedprefernces or sqlite database for persistence storage

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use `startActivityForResult();` instead of `startActivity();`. The difference occurs when you call `finish();` in the next Activity to close it after you set the difficulty.

- If you start the next Activity with `startActivityForResult();`, then
  `onActivityResult()` will get called in the original Activtiy (i.e.
  your previous game play), and you can resume play from there.
- When you use `startActivity();`, then `onActivityResult();` never gets
  called.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ive tried startActivityForResult(); but it gives a error that it is not applicable for the Arguments (Intent)

Comment: startActivitForResult(Intent, int) requires an int 'requestCode' as well as the Intent. This is actually very simple and extremely useful. You send any requestCode you want and it will get returned back to you later in onActivityResult() so you can tell what you just got back from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state of your game where the user left.
This you can do is by using Shared preferences.On continuing the game you would check the value of shared preference and fetch the values from their. For more information on how to save data in shared prefrneces see the official Android doc

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html